# How to get relative links in a README.md to work on a Github page?

Tags: github

I have a repo, where I use relative links in the main README.md. However, when I generate a Github page for the repo and use the README as the main index page, the links won't work. I suppose this is because I use relative links. Is there a way to make them work or do I need to replace all the links with absolute ones?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes

Comment: Yes, I have seen this page. Which part exactly are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see what you mean now.    You're not linking to the README.md directly but to the index.html in the gh-pages branch of the project.

If you add this to the head section of the index.html in the gh-pages branch of that project your links will work:

`<base href="http://www.github.com/alexvpopov/ruby-exercises/tree/master/">`

(If this breaks the stylesheets and images on that page then you'll just want to edit each link directly in that file to use the absolute URL.)

Comment: Funny thing, though - in order to prevent the problem with breaking the stylesheets, js etc., I have put the base tag as the last element of the `<head>` (and not as first as suggested by [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp).